# Why is scrolling with my Kivy ScrollView not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to scroll in a GridLayout, in which I created labels for different movie names.

I followed the Kivy documentaion and set one of the size_hints of the label to None. When I try to scroll nothing happends and the scroll bar doesn't appear either.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        movies = [
            "It Happened One Night", 
            "Citizen Kane", 
            "All About Eve", 
            "The Irishman", 
            "Singin' in the Rain", 
            "Double Indemnity", 
            "L.A. Confidential"
        ]
        
        self.rows = len(movies)
        # Iterate over list and add labels
        for i in movies:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=i, size_hint_y=None, font_size=50))


class ScrollableView(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        self.do_scroll_y = True
        self.size_hint_min = (0.5, 0.5)
        self.add_widget(Grid())


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableView()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size_hint_y = None` is required for the child of the `ScrollView`, but you are assigning it to the child of the child. Then you can bind the `height` of the `Grid` to the `minimum_height` property. Also, using `minimum_height` for the `Grid` requires that the children of the `Grid` have well defined `heights`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        movies = [
            "It Happened One Night",
            "Citizen Kane",
            "All About Eve",
            "The Irishman",
            "Singin' in the Rain",
            "Double Indemnity",
            "L.A. Confidential"
        ]

        self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))  # this insures that the height of the Grid can contain all the children

        self.rows = len(movies)
        # Iterate over list and add labels
        for i in movies:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=i, size_hint_y=None, height=100, font_size=50))  # note height setting

class ScrollableView(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        self.do_scroll_y = True
        self.size_hint_min = (0.5, 0.5)
        self.add_widget(Grid())


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableView()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```